# Click event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, mediaelement.js, mediaelement

I'm using mediaelement.js to play audio files. What I'm trying to do is track first button click and send it to Google analytics and then replace element class so second click won't be sent to GA. Here's the code:

```
$(function () {
    $(".aud-not-played .mejs-play").click(function () {
        $('.aud-not-played').attr('class', 'aud-played');
        setTimeout("_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Audio', 'Play', 'audtitle'])", 10000);
    })
});
```

And HTML code:

```
<div class="aud-not-played">
  <div id="mep_0" class="mejs-container svg  mejs-audio " style="width: 600px; height: 30px;">
    <div class="mejs-inner">
      <div class="mejs-mediaelement">
        <audio src="http://users.skynet.be/fa046054/home/P22/track06.mp3" style="display: none;">

        </audio>
      </div>
      <div class="mejs-layers">
        <div class="mejs-poster mejs-layer" style="display: none; width: 600px; height: 30px;">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mejs-controls">
        <div class="mejs-button mejs-playpause-button mejs-play">
          <button type="button" aria-controls="mep_0" title="Play/Pause">
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mejs-clear">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For some reason when I click on play button, code isn't executing. Do you know what could be the reason? Thanks

UPD: I replaced GA code with simple alert('Works!') to see if it's working:

```
$(function () {
    $(".aud-not-played .mejs-play").click(function () {
        alert('Works!');
        $('.aud-not-played').attr('class', 'aud-played');
    })
});
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML also please? So that we can the syntax for the buttons.

Comment: there's little to go on from what you've given but try     `$(function () {
        $(".mejs-play").one("click", function() { 
            setTimeout("_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Audio', 'Play', 'audtitle'])", 10000);
        })
    });`

Comment: Comment out code inside the click event and add an `alert('Test');`. See if you are getting the alert or not???

Answer (score 1):

I was having a very similar issue and found the only solution to be using a plugin along with the following function. Note, this has to be run on full page load and not page ready.

Plugin:  http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Oct/20/A-jquerywatch-Plugin-for-watching-CSS-styles-and-Attributes

```
$(window).load(function() {
    // Monitor play buttons
    $(".mejs-playpause-button").watch({
        properties: "top,left,opacity,attr_class",
        // Callback function when a change is detected
        callback: function(data, i) {
            if($(this).hasClass('mejs-pause')) {
                setTimeout("_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Audio', 'Play', 'audtitle'])", 10000);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '.aud-not-played .mejs-play', function () {

    if(!$(this).data('isClicked')) //if it the first click
        setTimeout("_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Audio', 'Play', 'audtitle'])", 10000);

    $(this).data({ isClicked: true }); //store the click check in jquerys cache
})
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't get it working. I tried on, one, bind, click. Nothing works on this button. I tried to change selector from .mejs-play to just .aud-not-played to see if it's working on other elements and it's working if I click anywhere else on the player but not on play/pause button.

Comment: on() is the only method that you should use of the ones you mentioned above. The closest thing would be `live`, which is deprecated (and replaced by `on`). Perhaps there is another element which is covering the actual button (with a higher z-index)?

Answer (score 0):

Use [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function of jquery.

```
$(function () {
    $(".aud-not-played .mejs-play").live('click',function () {
        $('.aud-not-played').attr('class', 'aud-played');
        setTimeout("_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Audio', 'Play', 'audtitle'])", 10000);
     })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to programmatically add an event Listener along the lines...

```
$('.mejs-playpause-button button[title="Play/Pause"]').on('click', function(e) {
//Do Whatever you want here        
console.log('addEventListener - playing') ;
});
```